# Which R package is suitable for parallel computing? How to speed up the given code?

Tags: r, loops, foreach, parallel-processing, doparallel

Which R package is the best for parallel computing?

I am interested in recommendations focused on processing time/vectorisation/user friendly syntax (looking for information valid in 01.2022 (including novelties)).

And here is the second part of the question:

I'd like to iterate through many (thousands) of vectors in a large list, so I'd like to speed it up.

Here is an example of what I can do. Inside the for loop I put some simple rescaling anonymous function just to provide the reprex. IRL I have more complicated computation to do. Can something lile this be speed up? How?

````
```{r}
library(foreach)
library(doParallel)

#this is dummy list of vecs:
set.seed(123)

v1 <- sample(600:800, 108, replace=TRUE)
v2 <- sample(600:800, 120, replace=TRUE)
v3 <- sample(550:800, 200, replace=TRUE)
v4 <- sample(640:800, 120, replace=TRUE)
v5 <- sample(700:810, 131, replace=TRUE)
v6 <- sample(600:800, 220, replace=TRUE)
v7 <- sample(600:850, 149, replace=TRUE)
v8 <- sample(530:800, 144, replace=TRUE)
v9 <- sample(600:810, 129, replace=TRUE)
v10 <- sample(600:860, 170, replace=TRUE)

list1 <- list()

list1[["first"]] <- v1
list1[["named"]] <- v2
list1[["vector"]] <- v3
list1[["out"]] <- v4
list1[["of"]] <- v5
list1[["many"]] <- v6
list1[["within"]] <- v7
list1[["this"]] <- v8
list1[["dummy"]] <- v9
list1[["list"]] <- v10


#this function rescales vectors within a given list to 0-255 range

parallelism_test <- function(list){
  # split list into chunks
  index_list = split(1:length(names(list1)), ceiling(1:length(names(list1))/100))
  
  #create empty list for extracted data
  newlist = list()
  
  # loop for parallel extraction
  for (indx in 1:length(index_list)){
    # use selected number of cores
    doParallel::registerDoParallel(cores = 5)
    # work in parallel (rescale vector to 0-255 range)
    newlist <- c(newlist, foreach::foreach(nam = names(list1)[index_list[[indx]]]) %dopar% (function (x) {(x - min(x))* (1/(max(x) - min(x))*255)})(list[[nam]]))}

  
  return(newlist)
}


test<- parallelism_test(list1)
print(test)
```
````

I will appreciate any advice.

Comment: https://cran.r-project.org/web/views/HighPerformanceComputing.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are quite a number of packages for parallel computing, but I often prefer the builtin `parallel` package.

In this case to code is quite clean

```
vscale <- function(x) {
  (x - min(x))/(max(x) - min(x))*255
}

library(parallel)
cl <- makeCluster(4)

list2 <- parLapply(cl, list1, vscale)
```

Although in this specific, I suspect that, storing your data in, for example, a `data.table` and use that, is in many cases faster. `data.table` will also use multiple threads if necessary. In the example below, I first create the `data.table` from the original list. It would, of course, be better in this case to make sure the data ends up in a `data.table` from the beginning.

```
library(data.table)

dta <- lapply(names(list1), 
  function(col) data.table(group = col, value = list1[[col]]))
dta <- rbindlist(dta)

dta[, value := vscale(value)]
```

Comment: In real life I have a few milions of named vectors. Each of them consists of a few hundreds of thousands values. I do not think data.table would fit here better than list (especially that I am at some point, producing an array for keras from this data, so preserving/accessing the given structure is essential for other code components). If you think otherwise, please could you explain it to me

Comment: If you need this structure later on, then I agree, then data.table is probably not a good solution.

Comment: @ramen If you are talking about those sizes of data, you might also have other issues:  1E6 vectors * 1E5 elements * 8 byte per element = 1E12 bytes = terabyte. You are then getting into the territory where you might want to start working with multiple computers. Within R this is possible with for example the `snow` package; but something like spark might be a better fit here.

Comment: I have a server space for the purpose of my computations, so it is not necessary to process the data with multiple machines. I just would like to take an advantage of using multiple workers and GPU acceleration and that would be enough for me.